# Calculate No. of Months and Days not Year Value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to calculate Months and Days between two dates without Year value. It also must be inclusive with start and end days. Thanks.

Comment: any code samples you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

## FULLY TESTED

In **C#** if you want **real months and days**, you must do some process:

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Parse("2011-01-01");
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Parse("2014-01-01");
// because of calculate from date1 at time 00:00 to date2 at time 00:00 we must add 1 day to date2
dt2 = dt2.AddDays(1);
int nMonths = 0;
while (dt1.AddMonths(1) <= dt2)
{
    dt1 = dt1.AddMonths(1);
    nMonths++;
}
int nDays = dt2.Subtract(dt1).Days;
return String.Format("{0}m{1}d", nMonths, nDays);
```

In **VB.net** if you want **real months and days**, you must do some process:

```
' http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/  
' http://codeconverter.sharpdevelop.net/SnippetConverter.aspx

Dim dt1 As DateTime = DateTime.Parse("2011-01-01")  
Dim dt2 As DateTime = DateTime.Parse("2014-01-01")
' because of calculate from date1 at time 00:00 to date2 at time 00:00 we must add 1 day to date2
dt2 = dt2.AddDays(1)  
Dim nMonths As Integer = 0  
While dt1.AddMonths(1) <= dt2  
    dt1 = dt1.AddMonths(1)  
    nMonths += 1  
End While  
Dim nDays As Integer = dt2.Subtract(dt1).Days  
Return String.Format("{0}m{1}d", nMonths, nDays)
```

In **MsSQL** if you want **real months and days**, you must do some process:

```
DECLARE @dt1 DATETIME
DECLARE @dt2 DATETIME
DECLARE @nDays INT
DECLARE @nMonths INT

SET @dt1 = '2011/01/01'
SET @dt2 = '2014/01/01'
-- because of calculate from date1 at time 00:00 to date2 at time 00:00 we must add 1 day to date2
SET dt2 = DATEADD(mm, 1, @dt1)
WHILE (DATEADD(mm, 1, @dt1) <= @dt2)
BEGIN
    SET @dt1 = DATEADD(mm, 1, @dt1)
    SET @nMonths = ISNULL(@nMonths, 0) + 1
END
SET @nDays = DATEDIFF(dd, @dt1, @dt2)

PRINT CAST(@nMonths AS VARCHAR) + 'm' + CAST(@nDays AS VARCHAR) + 'd'
-- you can create a sql function to get two date and return datediff as same as '5m8d'.
```

I hope be useful.

Comment: Can you plz help me in converting your code to vb.net.. Thanks

Comment: It is very easy: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Comment: I used your most above code of C# in Vb, like below:           While    (StDate.AddMonths(1) <= EndDate)
            StDate = StDate.AddMonths(1)
            ArrearMonths += 1
        End While
        ArrearDays = EndDate.Subtract(StDate).Days
        lblAmountWords.Text = String.Format("{0} Months , {1}  Days", ArrearMonths, ArrearDays), It gives me exclusive of last day which is not my requirement, I want to calculate like 17/05/2011 to 30/06/2011, it must be return 01 Month 15 Days, and for 01/07/2005 to 30/06/2006 it has to return 12 Months and 0 days. Thanks once again.

Comment: Well finally I got to solve the problem by getting One Day Back in StartDate and then achieved to Calculate it inclusive of Last/Start Day. Thanks.

Comment: ok, you right.
it calculate from date1 at time 00:00 to date2 at time 00:00;
so you must add 1 day to date2 and start process...

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how you want to calculate the days at the start and beginning. Do you want days at the start and end to be part of the number of days or should they be wrapped up in the number of months count? For example, If I am one week into the month in the start month and I am one week from the end in the end month I may have 20 days from the start month and 20 days from the end month, so would you want a count of 14 months and 40 days or would you prefer 15 months and 10 days?

If you would prefer the second solution simply count the number of days between the start and end date, divide by the average number of days in a month and declare the remainder as the day count.

Code below is aircode (not tested). It's a bit messy but it does the job.

```
int Days = DateDiff(day, StartDate, EndDate)
int Months = Math.Floor(Days / (365.25/12))
Days = Days - (Months * (365.25/12))
```

If you prefer the first method you simply extract the number of days from the count then count the number of months remaining and add the day count you originally extracted onto the count afterwards.

Like I said, it depends on what you want.

Comment: Craig, DateDiff is calculating the Day by excluding the Start and End Day. I used it for StartDate=01/07/2005 and EndDate=30/06/2006 and but Result is 11 Months 364 Days which is not my requirement. My Requirement in above Case is: '12 Months 0 Days' I am working on an accounting System, so only a single day matters, Please help me if you could so.

Comment: That's correct. If you are only entering in dates then the system will set the time at midnight (00:00) so you are only covering from 01/07/2005 00:00 to 30/06/2006 00:00. If you want to only enter dates but you want the system to count the who of the last day you need to add one day on (so that you are looking at 01/07/2006) or add one day and remove one second. This is how you would do that : `int Days = DateDiff(day, StartDate, DateAdd(minute,DateAdd(day, EndDate, 1), -1))` [Aircode].